# I'm trying to understand how to print all the possible combinations of a array

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, combinations, backtracking

```
i = start; 
while(i <= end and end - i + 1 >= r - index): 
    data[index] = arr[i]; 
    combinationUtil(arr, data, i + 1, 
                    end, index + 1, r); 
    i += 1;
```

I'm having a hard time trying to understand why, "end - i + 1 >= r - index" this condition is needed, I've tried running the code, with and without, it produced the same output, I want to know what is the edge case that causes this condition to return False.

[The full code is available here.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/)

Comment: I'm not sure if you're trying to understand this (incomplete) snippet or to solve the problem. If it's the latter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list

Comment: I'm trying to understand this snippet, the complete code is provided in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to group the variables into pieces that are easier to understand e.g.

```
int values_left_to_print = r - index; // (size of combination to be printed) - (current index into data)
int values_left_in_array = end - i + 1; // number of values left until the end of given arr
```

Now we can interpret it like this:

```
for (int i = start; i <= end && (values_left_in_array >= values_left_to_print); i++)  
{
```

so if `i` is near the `end` of the given array and there are not enough values left to print a full combination, then the loop (and function) will stop. Let's look at an example:

> Given
>
> ```
> arr = {1,2,3,4}
> n = 4; // size of arr
> r = 3; // size of combination
> ```
>
> The top level function will start to form a combination with 1 and then with 2 resulting in (1,2,3), (1,2,4), (1,3,4)
>
> It will not try 3 and 4, because `(values_left_in_array < values_left_to_print)`.
>
> If the condition was not there, then the function would try 3 and 4, but the values in the sequence only ever increase in index from left-to-right in the given array, so the combination will end because `i` will reach `end` before being able to find 3 values.